# AngularJs генерация json динамически из 2-х форм

Tags: json, angularjs, ng-repeat

[Пример](http://plnkr.co/edit/jsiVpVMtKzgmA0hI5KE1?p=preview)

Есть два типа форм представленные директивой `<add-form/>` и `<result-form/>` с помощью шаблонов, каждый тип выводится директивой ng-repeat.
Первый тип формы содержит название аргументов(количество форм - количество аргументов)
Второй тип формы - значение этих аргументов и результат который соответствует этим значениям. Это форма для неких юнит тестов, их количество может быть разным. Как записывать значения из нескольких форм второго типа в json в переменную value и results как в примере выше?

Немного изменил пример. Решил вопрос с `results`, осталась проблема с `value`.
http://plnkr.co/edit/jsiVpVMtKzgmA0hI5KE1?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="unit in units track by $index">
    <result-form/>
</div>
```

Где `<result-form/>` это

```
<div ng-repeat="arg in args track by $index">
          <div class="col-lg-3  value">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Argument value" ng-model="arg.value[$parent.$index]" required>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Как сделать чтобы  в  `$scope.args` в переменную `value` добавлялись значение без индекса как на скриншоте
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `value: ''` используйте `value: []`

Comment: супер ) благодарочка